# In Android, using exoplayer, how to fill surfaceview with a video that does not have the same aspect ratio with the device?

Tags: android, video, fullscreen, exoplayer

I have an activity that uses ExoPlayer to play a video. When I go fullscreen, unless the aspect ratio of the device is equal to that of the video, I get small black bars at the top and the bottom of the video.

This is how the layout looks :

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer.AspectRatioFrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/video_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/surface_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"/>

    <View android:id="@+id/shutter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"/>

</com.google.android.exoplayer.AspectRatioFrameLayout>
```

I was hoping that

```
aspectRatioFrameLayout.setAspectRatio(mVideo.getAspectRatio());
```

would solve the problem, but I had no success. 
Is there a way to fill the screen with the video, even if part of the video is cut off from the screen?

Comment: late to the party, and on the opposite side: how do you make sure that `SurfaceView` + `AspectRatioFrameLayout` keep correct aspect ratio and also fill screen height and/or width as much as possible? Do you match_parent on `SurfaceView` and ... what on `AspectRatioFrameLayout`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can **remove** the `com.google.android.exoplayer.AspectRatioFrameLayout`.

Next, put a simple `FrameLayout` with width and height on `match_parent`.

Note that the `SurfaceView` should stay in width and height = `match_parent`.

Explanation: `AspectRatioFrameLayout` is setting the correct height of the view according to the real video ratio (calcuclating based on width, height and pixelRatio). If you don't wan't this, Exoplayer can still display the view on a `SurfaceView` as they was doing before. If the `SurfaceView` is not `@Override` it will not have aspect ratio.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the late reply...it worked! So easy, just changing to frame layout did the trick

Answer (score 12):

There is a fastest way to fill the screen with the video.
Go to the `SimpleExoPlayerView.java` class, change the `resizeMode` from `AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FIT` to `AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL`.
`RESIZE_MODE_FILL` will ignore the specified aspect ratio.
Use this way if you use ExoPlayer as a module in your project.

**UPDATED**
If you use ExoPlayer as a library, they have a method to `setResizeMode()`.
You just set to `AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL` in your view:
`simpleExoPlayerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL)`
That's all!

Comment: simpleExoPlayerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL); its helpful for fill the parent view with player.

Comment: what if i want to set aspect ratio

Comment: If you want to keep the video's aspect ratio but expand it to the full view size, use fixed_width if your video is taller than it is wide (portrait) or fixed_height if it's wider than it is tall (landscape)

Comment: Its deprecated , what's the solution now ?

Comment: The question is asking for a SurfaceView, not a SimpleExoPlayerView

Answer (score 11):

This can be done in XML as well if you use `SimpleExoPlayerView`.

Just add `app:resize_mode="zoom"` to keep video's aspect ratio or `app:resize_mode="fill"` if you don't care about aspect ratio.

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
            android:id="@+id/video"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:resize_mode="zoom" />
```

Comment: The `resize_mode` tag is also there on `com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView` for me. Easiest solution by far. +1

Comment: The question is asking for a SurfaceView, not a SimpleExoPlayerView

Answer (score 3):

Simply use bellow line in your xml. It'll work perfectly.

```
app:resize_mode="fill"
```

Comment: There's no such parameter for a SurfaceView